# What are some options to show different parts of an article to different users?

Tags: acl, content-filtering, content-plugin

I have some information/data that is personal (not necessarily secret) and I want a menu entry to show the information relevant for the logged in user.

On the page there are also some common information, so having separate articles are impractical.

What are my options? I have seen plugins that selected content based on ACL or userids, but all of them seems to have gone missing.

Are there other "standard" options that I'm not aware of?

If I were to write myself a plugin, what are good resources for this particular type of plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading the [OSD Content Restriction plugin](https://documentation.form2content.com/f2c-extensions/joomla-content-restriction-plugin). The actual download has disappeared and gives you a 404, but I dug it up using Wayback Machine. I fixed the few incompatibilities in the source code and have it working in Joomla 4/PHP 8.2.

It allows you to conditionally show parts of an article, and one of the conditions are `{user NN}`. E.g.

```
This is common content. {user 101}And this is only for user 100.{/user}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used Articles Anywhere from Regular Labs, https://regularlabs.com/articlesanywhere, to do something that sounds similar to what you are describing.

The common information is placed in an article that has a viewing level of Public while the private or limited access information is placed in article(s) with an ACL viewing level to limit who can see the restricted information.

Use Articles Anywhere tags to include the private articles within the 'common' article or you can create another article that uses AA to include the common and the private articles. The context of your requirement will determine which approach is best for you.

When viewing the 'parent' or base article, all visitors will see the common information and if they are logged in they will see the additional private information they are entitled to according to their ACL for the private article(s).